# Skewed DataFrame in Pandas when making a new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Data frame called tinytimetable that looks like this:

```
      stepnr  stepred    max1d  max2d  1dlink  2dlink
0          2   3.0000   0.2880   15.0    4136       0
1          4  14.4841  14.4841   15.0    4730       0
2          6   7.4591   7.4591   15.0    4136       0
3          8  14.2190  14.2190   15.0    4136       0
4          9  12.9565  12.9565   15.0    4136       0
5         10  14.6573  14.6573   15.0    4136       0
6         11  13.9158  13.9158   15.0    4136       0 
...
```

I want to make a new DataFrame with only the first two colums stepnr and stepred. The stepnr has to be the index of the new DataFrame. like this:

```
stepnr   stepred 
     2    3.0000  
     4   14.4841  
     6    7.4591   
     8   14.2190  
     9   12.9565 
     10  14.6573 
     11  13.9158
             ...
```

I tried:

```
tcalc= pandas.DataFrame(tinytimetable['stepred'], index=tinytimetable['stepnr'])
```

This however gave the following result:

```
        stepred
stepnr         
2        7.4591
4       12.9565
6       13.9158
8       14.1477
9       14.0405
10      14.0480
11      14.0196
```

As you can see it gets skewed where the number 2 gets the value of the number 6. How do I change this code to make the DataFrame correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by selecting the two columns and use `set_index`:

```
tcalc = tinytimetable[['stepred','stepnr']].set_index('stepnr')
```

and you get tcalc:

```
        stepred
stepnr         
2        3.0000
4       14.4841
6        7.4591
8       14.2190
9       12.9565
10      14.6573
11      13.9158
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try first slicing the DataFrame, then setting the index:

```
tcalc = pandas.DataFrame(tinytimetable.loc[:, ['stepred', 'stepnr']]).set_index('stepnr'))
```